# How to change style on Leaflet Map after props update?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

A country is divided into 4 zones: North, East, South and West. There are many states in each zone. There is a dropdown in the App component to select the zone. It is passed down to the Map component as a prop. Which state belongs to which zone is present in the geoJSON file. The geoJSON file also contains the boundaries of each state drawn as a polygon.

***What I want:***
I would like to color the states based on the zone selected. For example, when North zone is selected from the dropdown, the corresponding states are colored in Red. So, whenever there is an in props (selected zone), the corresponding states should be colored.

***What I have done:***
I was able to color the states based on the zones using the code below.

***Issue faced:***
On selecting a new zone from the dropdown, the map doesn't move. The map remains fixed at the position specified in setView. Or, if I create an alert, the alert doesn't go away on clicking 'OK'.

***Map Component***

```
componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ selectedZone: this.props.selectedZone})
        var map = L.map("map").setView([17.3850, 78.4867], 10);
        L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            attribution: "OK",
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1
        }).addTo(map);

        L.geoJSON(statesData, {style: this.style}).addTo(map);    
    }

componentDidUpdate(nextProps) {
        if(this.state.selectedZone != nextProps.selectedZone){
            this.setState({ selectedZone: nextProps.selectedZone})
        }
        var container = L.DomUtil.get('map');
        if(container != null){
            container._leaflet_id = null;
        }
        var map = L.map("map").setView([17.3850, 78.4867], 10);
        L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
            attribution: "OK",
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1
        }).addTo(map);

        L.geoJSON(statesData, {style: this.style}).addTo(map);    
    }
```

I feel that my mistake lies in the componentDidUpdate() function and that there is a better way to style the map with change in props.

Please let me know if anything is not clear or any extra information is required.

Many thanks!

Comment: You should use the same map instance in mount and update. And where do you want to pan the map? You are using the same coords in `setView`

Comment: Please help with how I can use the same map instance. If I declare 'map' outside the class or if I don't declare it in componentDidMount(), I get an error "Map container not found." If I directly use L.geoJSON(statesData, {style: this.style}).addTo(map) in componentDidUpdate(), I get an error - "map is not declared." I just want to be able to pan the map rather than having it fixed.

Comment: Could you make a demo with what you have so far?